# ShareThis WP Plugin - Disable onhhover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have this installed on my wordpress website; http://sharethis.com/

The plugin works great and adds a nice 'ShareThis' button at the end of all my posts.

***BUT***. For an odd reason,  it acts and works on hover, as opposed to onclick -- very odd. Could anyone suggest where I can disable this on hover and direct to onclick like normal buttons??!

Here is the share this plugin script, which I'm assuming is where I'll need to add:

```
if (!window.console || !console.firebug) {
    var names = ["log", "debug", "info", "warn", "error", "assert", "dir", "dirxml", "group", "groupEnd",
                 "time", "timeEnd", "count", "trace", "profile", "profileEnd"];
    window.console = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) window.console[names[i]] = function() {};
}


var startPos=1;

function st_log() {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'WordPressPlugin', 'ConfigOptionsUpdated']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'WordPressPlugin', "Type_" + $("#st_current_type").val()]);
    if ($("#get5x").attr("checked")) {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'WordPressPlugin', "Version_5x"]);
    } else if ($("#get4x").attr("checked")) {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'WordPressPlugin', "Version_4x"]);
    }
}

function getStartPos(){
    var arr=[];
    arr['_large']=1;
    arr['_hcount']=2;
    arr['_vcount']=3;
    arr['classic']=4;
    arr['chicklet']=5;
    arr['chicklet2']=6;
    arr['_buttons']=7;
    if(typeof(arr[st_current_type])!=="undefined"){
        startPos=arr[st_current_type];
    }
}


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    getStartPos();
    if(/updated=true/.test(document.location.href)){
        $('#st_updated').show();
    }
    jQuery("#carousel").jcarousel({
        size:7,
        scroll:1,
        visible:1,
        start:startPos,
        wrap:"circular",
        itemFirstInCallback: {
          onAfterAnimation: carDoneCB
        },
        itemFallbackDimension:460
    });

    $('#st_services').bind('keyup', function(){
        clearTimeout(stkeytimeout);
        stkeytimeout=setTimeout(function(){makeTags();},500);
    })

    $('#st_pkey').bind('keyup', function(){
        clearTimeout(stpkeytimeout);
        stpkeytimeout=setTimeout(function(){makeHeadTag();},500);
    })

    var services=$('#st_services').val();
    svc=services.split(",");
    for(var i=0;i<svc.length;i++){
        if (svc[i]=="fblike"){
            $('#st_fblike').attr('checked','checked');
        } else if (svc[i]=="plusone"){
            $('#st_plusone').attr('checked','checked');
        }
    }

    $('#st_fblike').bind('click', function(){
        if ($('#st_fblike').attr('checked')) {
            if ($('#st_services').val().indexOf("fblike")==-1) {
                var pos=$('#st_services').val().indexOf("plusone");
                if (pos==-1)
                    $('#st_services').val($('#st_services').val()+",fblike");
                else {
                    var str=$('#st_services').val();
                    if (pos==0)
                        $('#st_services').val("fblike,"+str.substr(pos));
                    else
                        $('#st_services').val(str.substr(0,pos-1)+",fblike"+str.substr(pos-1));
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            var pos=$('#st_services').val().indexOf("fblike");
            if (pos!=-1) {
                var str=$('#st_services').val();
                if (pos==0)
                    $('#st_services').val(str.substr(pos+7));
                else
                    $('#st_services').val(str.substr(0,pos-1)+str.substr(pos+6));
            }
        }
        clearTimeout(stpkeytimeout);
        stpkeytimeout=setTimeout(function(){makeTags();},500);
    })

    $('#st_plusone').bind('click', function(){
        if ($('#st_plusone').attr('checked')) {
            if ($('#st_services').val().indexOf("plusone")==-1) {
                $('#st_services').val($('#st_services').val()+",plusone");
            }
        }
        else {
            var pos=$('#st_services').val().indexOf("plusone");
            if (pos!=-1) {
                var str=$('#st_services').val();
                if (pos==0)
                    $('#st_services').val(str.substr(pos+8));
                else
                    $('#st_services').val(str.substr(0,pos-1)+str.substr(pos+7));
            }
        }
        clearTimeout(stpkeytimeout);
        stpkeytimeout=setTimeout(function(){makeTags();},500);
    })
});

var stkeytimeout=null;
var stpkeytimeout=null;

function makeHeadTag(){
    var val=$('#st_pkey').val();
    var tag=$('#st_widget').val();
    var reg=new RegExp("(publisher:)('|\")(.*?)('|\")",'gim');
    var b=tag.replace(reg,'$1$2'+val+'$4');
    $('#st_widget').val(b);
}


function makeTags(){
    var services=$('#st_services').val();
    var type=$('#curr_type').html();
    svc=services.split(",");
    var tags=""
    var dt="displayText='share'";
    if(type=="chicklet2"){
        dt="";
    }else if(type=="classic"){
        tags="<span class='st_sharethis' st_title='<?php the_title(); ?>' st_url='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' displayText='ShareThis'></span>";
        $('#st_tags').val(tags);
        return true;
    }
    if(type=="chicklet" || type=="chicklet2" || type=="classic"){
        type="";
    }
    for(var i=0;i<svc.length;i++){
        if(svc[i].length>2){
            tags+="<span class='st_"+svc[i]+type+"' st_title='<?php the_title(); ?>' st_url='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' "+dt+"></span>";
        }
    }
    $('#st_tags').val(tags);

}


function carDoneCB(a,elem){
    var type=elem.getAttribute("st_type");
    $('.services').show()
    $('.fblikeplusone').show();
    if(type=="vcount"){
        $('#curr_type').html("_vcount");$("#st_current_type").val("_vcount");
        $('#currentType').html("<span class='type_name'>Vertical Count</span>");
    }else if(type=="hcount"){
            $('#curr_type').html("_hcount");$("#st_current_type").val("_hcount");
            $('#currentType').html("<span class='type_name'>Horizontal Count</span>");
    }else if(type=="buttons"){
            $('#curr_type').html("_buttons");$("#st_current_type").val("_buttons");
            $('#currentType').html("<span class='type_name'>Buttons</span>");
    }else if(type=="large"){
            $('#curr_type').html("_large");$("#st_current_type").val("_large");
            $('#currentType').html("<span class='type_name'>Large Icons</span>");
    }else if(type=="chicklet"){
            $('#curr_type').html("chicklet");$("#st_current_type").val("chicklet");
            $('#currentType').html("<span class='type_name'>Regular Buttons</span>");
    }else if(type=="chicklet2"){
            $('#curr_type').html("chicklet2");$("#st_current_type").val("chicklet2");
            $('#currentType').html("<span class='type_name'>Regular Buttons No-Text</span>");
    }else if(type=="sharethis"){
            $('.services').hide();
            $('.fblikeplusone').hide();
            $('#curr_type').html("classic");$("#st_current_type").val("classic");
            $('#currentType').html("<span class='type_name'>Classic</span>");
    }   
    makeTags(); 
}

$(".versionItem").click(function() {
    $(".versionItem").removeClass("versionSelect");
    $(this).addClass("versionSelect");  
});
```

**Update:** Their documentation discusses this; http://help.sharethis.com/customization/hover-effects.

I've just unsuccessfully tried to duplicate within the code window they provide with the below: *(No, I didn't keep asterisks within)*

```
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script><script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher:'29b6d061-87e2-4726-9341-a2a77f404df6'});    

stLight.options({ 
var st_type='wordpress3.2.1',
**onhover: false**
 });
</script>
```

**So, I guess, how do I disable it within their Wordpress Plugin Version????**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few methods for adding a `mouseover` event listener:

jQuery:

```
$(selector).hover(function() { }, function() { });
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById(selector).addEventListener('mouseover', function() { }, false);
document.getElementById(selector).addEventListener('mouseout', function() { }, false);
```

However, I do not see either of these methods used in this code. This leads me to believe that there are being declared elsewhere. Can you provide more info?

Comment: is it possible to use $('.selector').unbind('hover') to prevent the plugin from showing up when the mouse is over?

Comment: You can do that, but you'll need to figure out which selector the behavior is attached to. This is the `div` that displays when the button is hovered on: <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.6; position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 89999990; display: block; " id="stOverlay"></div>. See if you can find `$('#stOverlay')` in the code and back pedal from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wordpress, Go to settings > sharethis > place the onhover:false in the "Click to modify other widget options" section under the stLight.options

Works for me.

Comment: Using Version 7.0.6 I don't see that option. I see "Choose More Options" on step 1 but no option from the 3 listed thumbnails to remove the hover :( (would make sense though)